# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows, while callin dll from java

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am calling a DLL (compiled with GCC) through Java, using JDK 1.7.0_40 on Windows 7. I had copied the generated `hello.dll` to my `java/bin` directory and am executing `HelloJNI.java` from the console.

I am recieving this error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x610d70b4, pid=1956, tid=3960
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_40-b43) (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.0-b56 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [cygwin1.dll+0xd70b4]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\workspace\HelloJNI\hs_err_pid1956.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

My header file, generated with `java -jni HelloJNI`:

```c
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class HelloJNI */

#ifndef _Included_HelloJNI
#define _Included_HelloJNI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     HelloJNI
 * Method:    sayHello
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

My C code, compiled with `gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -I"d:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\include" -I"d:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\include\win32" -shared -o hello.dll HELLOJNI.c`:

```c
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HelloJNI.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello(JNIEnv *env,jobject thisObj) {
printf("Hai Welcome");
return;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have a bug in your JNI code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gyro Gearless, i have added my code

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can't link to the cygwin dll for jni code, its incompatible with what the jvm is compiled and linked against. try `-mno-cygwin` , t

Comment: i cant get you Please suggest me what is -mno.

Comment: @Bala -mno-cygwin is a compiler flag, use it when you compile/link your jni code.

Comment: gcc -mno-cygwin -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -I"d:\Progra Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\include" -I"d:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\include\win32" -shared -o hello.dll HELLOJNI.c
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mno-cygwin’

Answer (score 0):

Well, Here is my solution for this issue.

I solved this problem on cygwin32 with gcc 4.9.3.

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-4.9.3-1.i686/src/gcc-4.9.3/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-4.9.3-1.i686/src/gcc-4.9.3
--prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=i686-
pc-cygwin --host=i686-pc-cygwin --target=i686-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared --ena
ble-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-arch=i686 --wit
h-tune=generic --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,java,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-
libatomic --enable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --enable-libssp --enable-libada --enable-libjava --enabl
e-libgcj-sublibs --disable-java-awt --disable-symvers --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/ecj.jar --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/inc
lude/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.3 (GCC)
```

And java version is here

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

1. compile the source code

   gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -D__int64="long long" -c HelloJNI.c -o HelloJNI.o -I/where/java1.7/include -Iwhere/java1.7/include/win32
2. create def file like, VC++ way of making .def file.

   dlltool --output-def HelloJNI.def --kill-at --add-stdcall-alias --dllname HelloJNI.dll HelloJNI.o
3. modify the def file, for this example HelloJNI.def
   you can see the contents of the file looks like as following

   ; dlltool --output-def HelloJNI.def --kill-at --add-stdcall-alias --dllname HelloJNI.dll HelloJNI.o
   EXPORTS
       Java_com_tobee_jni_test_HelloJNI_message = Java_com_tobee_jni_test_HelloJNI_message@8 @ 1
       Java_com_tobee_jni_test_HelloJNI_message@8 @ 2

You've got some strange things found while going through the lines.
I've just defined only one static JNI method but two methods there.
so, remove second line and left part of equal('=') of first line
then it must be below...

```
; dlltool --output-def HelloJNI.def --kill-at --add-stdcall-alias --dllname HelloJNI.dll HelloJNI.o
EXPORTS
    Java_com_tobee_jni_test_HelloJNI_message@8 @ 1
```

4. With dlltool command, I think i can adjust my dll with def file i modified above like dllexport in windows programming.

   dlltool --output-lib libHelloJNI.a --input-def HelloJNI.def --kill-at --add-stdcall-alias --dllname HelloJNI.dll HelloJNI.o
5. One last thing is making a library with name whatever you want

   gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -shared -m32 HelloJNI.o -o HelloJNI.dll -Wall -L -IHelloJNI

I have no trouble with the process.

Here is my source code

```
class HelloJNI{

   private native String message();


   public static void main( String[] args ){
      System.out.println("=====>" + new HelloJNI().message());
   }

   static{
     System.loadLibrary( "HelloJNI" );
   }
}
```

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HelloJNI.h"

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_tobee_jni_test_HelloJNI_message( JNIEnv *env, jobject obj ){
   char buf[128];
   sprintf(buf, "this is my message\r\n");

   return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buf);
}
```

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_tobee_jni_test_HelloJNI */

#ifndef _Included_com_tobee_jni_test_HelloJNI
#define _Included_com_tobee_jni_test_HelloJNI
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_tobee_jni_test_HelloJNI
 * Method:    message
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_tobee_jni_test_HelloJNI_message
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```